# Where did I go wrong in ket vector in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space

Consider a system of total angular momentum j = 1. The operator jx is given by:

[image]

What are the possible values when measuring jx?

My attempt:

The eigenvalues after calculation are -1, 0, 1.

Now I want to find the eigenvector when eigenvalue is 1.

[image]

-x + y = 0

x - y + z = 0

y - z = 0

Therefore, x = 1, y = 1, z = 1.

|1> = [image]

But the solution given in the textbook is:

|1> = [image]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your result does not fulfill $x - y + z + 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\hbar=1$, your matrix
$$j_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 &1 &0}$$
has the igenvalues $1,0$ and $-1$ as you stated. But when you wnat to get the eigenvectors, you must use the factor $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. That is, the system you have to solve is
$$\pmatrix{-1 &1/\sqrt 2 & 0\\1/\sqrt 2 &-1 &1/\sqrt 2\\0&1/\sqrt 2&-1}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$$
Solving this will yield the correct result.